# Kotlin Inheritance - Create child instance using parent contructor

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Considering the the parent class:

```
abstract class Parent(
  val arg1: TypeArg1 = defValue,
  val arg2: TypeArg2 = defValue,
  ....
)
```

and

```
class Child : Parent()
```

Is there anyway in Kotlin to create a `Child` instance using `Parent` constructor? Like:

```
val child = Child(arg1, arg2)
```

I want to avoid doing the proxy like:

```
class Child(
  val arg1: TypeArg1 = defValue,
  val arg2: TypeArg2 = defValue,
) : Parent(arg1, arg2)
```

I inherit `Parent` in many classes and doing a such a declaration of `Child` constructor is really unnecessary.

Is there any way to avoid this and just create the instance of child using its parent construcor.

Answer (score 2):

The language doesn't have an automated way, but IntelliJ IDEA can auto-generate it for you.

Type

```
class Child: Parent()
```

and then press Alt + Enter and it will give the option to *Add constructor parameter(s) ___...*.